# In Markov inequality proof, why is $\int_a^\infty xp(x) \, dx \ge \int_a^\infty ap(x) \, dx$

Tags: probability, integration, law-of-large-numbers

**Markov inequality**,

$$\Pr(X \ge a) \le \frac{E[x]}{a}$$

Proof

$$\begin{aligned} 
    E(X) &= \int_0^\infty xp(x)\,dx = \int_0^a xp(x)\,dx + \int_a^\infty xp(x)\,dx \\  
    &\ge \int_a^\infty xp(x)\,dx \ge \int_a^\infty ap(x) \, dx 
\end{aligned}$$

Why is the last inequality true?
Why is it ok to change $x$ to $a$, and we know it is less than or equal to?
How did they figure it out?
Thanks!

Comment: Because $x\geq a$ over the interval of integration.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your title has the inequality sign the wrong way around.

Comment: You are integrating over the region $x\in[a,\infty)$, so $x>a$. if you make the integrand smaller, then the integral is smaller.

Comment: @FH93 How do you know $x \ge a$ over the integration?  I remember learning a theorem like that in real analysis.

Comment: @user13985 The lower limit on the integral is $a$; and the interval of integration is given by the real values of x in between $a$ and the upper limit. Clearly the upper limit is greater than $a$, so that $x\geq a$ in the integral.

Comment: @FH93 That's very thorough, and I can see it for $\int _{x}^{\infty} xdx \ge \int _{a}^{infty}adx$, but does it still work with probability p(x) inside?  Just wanted to make sure I did not misunderstand you.

Comment: @user13985 $p(x)\geq 0$, as mentioned below in the answer, so $x\geq a \implies xp(x) \geq ap(x)$. The key result is: if $f,g:[a,\infty]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) \geq g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,\infty]$ then $\int_a^{\infty} f(x) dx \geq \int_a^{\infty} g(x)dx$ (think of the integrals as areas under the respective curves).

Comment: @FH93 Thanks, that explains the reason well.  Do you want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\ge a$, 
$$
xp(x) \ge ap(x)
$$
and using positivity of $\int$ and $p(x)$:
$$
\int_a^\infty xp(x) \,dx \ge \int_a^\infty  ap(x) \,dx
$$

Comment: Maybe you should also mention non-negativity of $p(x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't see why this is true.  Does that mean $\int xdx \ge \int adx$

Comment: I added in bounds of integration to improve the formatting a bit.